# How to position number of objects, spacing each object 2 units from one another so all objects will be centered?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a group of bottles on a table that I want to arrange in a straight line such that each bottle will have a space of 2 cm from the bottles that are next to him. Also, the group must be centered on the table. 
How can I know the position of each bottle for n bottles (in 2 dimensional space).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a rough sketch of the layout you want. Since you say :"in a straight line" it sounds like arranging the bottles on a diameter will work.

Comment: @EthanBolker I mean that each bottle will be placed right next to each other like this:       

Comment: It sounds like you can choose any line you want as long as it passes through the center of the table and is long enough. The diagonal is the longest such line, but sometimes a line parallel to an axis will do. If the number of bottles is odd, one bottle will be at the center of the table; if the number is even, the center will be between two bottles. Draw a complete picture of the table and the bottles and see if you can't figure out their coordinates. If you run into difficulty, please be very specific about what the difficulty was.